# Can you use an Android as NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc

So iv been editing and working with NTAG215 type NFC tags and writing data to them etc. Would it be possible to use an android as a tag and have it be read by a different system, for example a WiiU or Switch. Host Card Emulation?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, and no. I'm assuming you want to use your android to emulate an Amiibo, so here is what I found out.

The problem with Android's Host Card Emulation (HCE) is that it [supports](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#SupportedProtocols)  ISO 14443-4 for NFC tag emulation and the Amiibo/NTAG215 is an older version  of this ISO (14443-2). So no for Android, unless your phone is rooted and you somehow go around this restriction. This [guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/amiibo/comments/2td7h2/amiibo_nfchce_question/cp3i19m/) apparently has some good insights on the issue you are having.

However, it turns out you can do this by using some older version of Cyanogen Mod. I did not find the any code for this because of copyright infringement. So be mindful of that when you code your app and share it.